# Appending a suffix to a list of variables

Tags: stata

Is there a way to quickly append the same suffix to a list of variables from monthly reports in Stata for example:

Variable list: report, total_enrollment

Append _jan22 so new variable list: report_jan22, total_enrollment_jan22

Variable list: report, total_enrollment

Append _feb22 so new variable list: report_feb22, total_enrollment_feb22

Have looked at the Rename * command -- advice on using this command?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple datasets or how can the variables have the same name in the first place?

One way to solve this would be to use a loop. Provide more detail if this does not work.

```
clear 
set obs 10

gen report = 1
gen total_enrollment = 1

local vars report total_enrollment
foreach var of local vars {
    rename `var' `var'_jan22
}
```

Comment: `rename (report total_enrollment) (=_jan22)` is another way to do it, without any loop.

Comment: Thank you for the example! These worked very well. There are multiple datasets with the same variables but covering different years.